# Fallo en un proyecto de un curso que estoy realizando

Tags: php, json, foreach

Hola muy buenas me encuentro realizando un proyecto y me he encontrado con este error:

> Notice: Undefined index: registro in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\validar_registro.php on line 25
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\includes\funciones\funciones.php on line 29
>        string(20) "{"pase_completo":50}"
>        string(2) "[]"

Este es el error que me arroja y no consigo encontrar cual es el fallo que tengo. Mi código es el siguiente:

En este primero que introduzco es el error de la linea 23 que lo he subrayado para que sea mas fácil de encontrar:

```
<?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>
<section class="seccion contenedor">
        <h2>Resumen Registro</h2>

    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])):  /*Esto es para asegurarnkos que la variable submit existe*/

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $regalo = $_POST['regalo'];
    $total = $_POST['total_pedido'];
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // Pedidos
    $boletos = $_POST['boletos'];
    $camisas = $_POST['pedido_camisas'];
    $etiquetas = $_POST['pedido_etiquetas']; //Lo que hare es coger estas tres y pasarla a una funcion que me regresara como Jason que estara en funciones.php
    include_once 'includes/funciones/funciones.php';
    $pedido = productos_json($boletos, $camisas, $etiquetas);

    //eventos
    $eventos = $_POST['registro'];
    $registro = eventos_json($eventos);
    ?>

     <pre>
    <?php var_dump($pedido); ?>
    </pre>

    <hr>

    <pre>
    <?php var_dump($registro); ?>
    </pre>

     <?php endif;/*Cierre del if para revisar el submit*/ ?>
```

Exactamente la linea 23 es `$eventos = $_POST['registro'];`

Y el segundo aviso que es un warning el código es este:

```
<?php 
function productos_json(&$boletos, &$camisas = 0, &$etiquetas = 0){ 

    $dias = array(0 => 'un_dia', 1=> 'pase_completo', 2=> 'pase_2dias');
    $total_boletos = array_combine($dias, $boletos);   
    $json = array();
    foreach($total_boletos as $key => $boletos):
            if((int) $boletos > 0):
                $json[$key] = (int) $boletos;
            endif ;   
    endforeach;

    $camisas = (int) $camisas;
    if($camisas > 0):
        $json['camisas'] = $camisas;
    endif;

    $etiquetas = (int) $etiquetas;
    if($etiquetas > 0):
        $json['etiquetas'] = $etiquetas;
    endif;

    return json_encode($json);
}

function eventos_json(&$eventos) {
    $eventos_json = array(); 
    foreach($eventos as $evento):
    $eventos_json['eventos'] [] = $evento;
endforeach;

return json_encode($eventos_json); /
}
```

Y la línea 29 es esta `foreach($eventos as $evento):`

He revisado el código varias veces para encontrar algún fallo de sintaxis pero no he encontrado nada, llevo aquí atrancado dos días sin conseguir darle una solución. Sería de gran ayuda vuestra colaboración, muchas gracias de antemano por todo.

Yo sustraigo la información de un archivo llamado registro.php, el codigo es este:

```
<?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>

    <section class="seccion contenedor">
        <h2>Registro de Usuarios</h2>
        <form id="registro" class="registro" action="validar_registro.php" method="post"> 
        <div id="datos_usuario" class="registro caja clearfix"> 
            <div class="campo">
                <label for="nombre"><span>*</span>Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Tu Nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="campo">
                    <label for="apellido"><span>*</span>Apellido:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Tu Apellido">
                </div>
            <div class="campo">
                    <label for="email"><span>*</span>Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Tu Email">
                </div>
            <div id="error"></div>
        </div><!--.#datos_usuarios-->

        <div id="paquetes" class="paquetes">
            <h3>Elige el número de boletos</h3>
            <ul class="lista-precios clearfix">
                    <li>
                        <div class="tabla-precio">
                            <h3>Pase por día (viernes)</h3>
                            <p class="numero">30€</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Bocadillos Gratis</li>
                                <li>Todas las Conferencias</li>
                                <li>Todos los talleres</li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="orden">
                                    <label for="pase_dia">Boletos deseados:</label>
                                    <input type="number" min="0" id="pase_dia" size="3" name="boletos[]" placeholder="0">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <div class="tabla-precio">
                            <h3>Todos los días</h3>
                            <p class="numero">50€</p>
                            <ul>
                                 <li>Bocadillos Gratis</li>
                                 <li>Todas las Conferencias</li>
                                 <li>Todos los talleres</li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="orden">
                                    <label for="pase_completo">Boletos deseados:</label>
                                    <input type="number" min="0" id="pase_completo" size="3" name="boletos[]" placeholder="0">
                                </div>

                     </li>
                     <li>
                             <div class="tabla-precio">
                                <h3>Pase por 2 días (viernes y sábado)</h3>
                                <p class="numero">45€</p>
                                <ul>
                                     <li>Bocadillos Gratis</li>
                                     <li>Todas las Conferencias</li>
                                     <li>Todos los talleres</li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="orden">
                                        <label for="pase_dosdias">Boletos deseados:</label>
                                        <input type="number" min="0" id="pase_dosdias" size="3" name="boletos[]" placeholder="0">
                                    </div>
                             </div>
                     </li>
                </ul>
        </div><!--.#paquetes-->

        <div id="eventos" class="eventos clearfix"> 
                <h3>Elige tus talleres</h3>
                <div class="caja">
                      <div id="viernes" class="contenido-dia clearfix">
                          <h4>Viernes</h4>
                              <div>
                                  <p>Talleres:</p>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_01" value="taller_01"><time>10:00</time> Responsive Web Design</label>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_02" value="taller_02"><time>12:00</time> Flexbox</label>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_03" value="taller_03"><time>14:00</time> HTML5 y CSS3</label>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_04" value="taller_04"><time>17:00</time> Drupal</label>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_05" value="taller_05"><time>19:00</time> WordPress</label>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                  <p>Conferencias:</p>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_01" value="conf_01"><time>10:00</time> Como ser Freelancer</label>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_02" value="conf_02"><time>17:00</time> Tecnologías del Futuro</label>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_03" value="conf_03"><time>19:00</time> Seguridad en la Web</label>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                  <p>Seminarios:</p>
                                  <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="sem_01" value="sem_01"><time>10:00</time> Diseño UI y UX para móviles</label>
                              </div>
                      </div> <!--#viernes-->
                      <div id="sabado" class="contenido-dia clearfix">
                          <h4>Sábado</h4>
                          <div>
                                <p>Talleres:</p>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_06" value="taller_06"><time>10:00</time> AngularJS</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_07" value="taller_07"><time>12:00</time> PHP y MySQL</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_08" value="taller_08"><time>14:00</time> JavaScript Avanzado</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_09" value="taller_09"><time>17:00</time> SEO en Google</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_10" value="taller_10"><time>19:00</time> De Photoshop a HTML5 y CSS3</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_11" value="taller_11"><time>21:00</time> PHP Medio y Avanzado</label>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                                <p>Conferencias:</p>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_04" value="conf_04"><time>10:00</time> Como crear una tienda online que venda millones en pocos días</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_05" value="conf_05"><time>17:00</time> Los mejores lugares para encontrar trabajo</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_06" value="conf_06"><time>19:00</time> Pasos para crear un negocio rentable</label>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                                <p>Seminarios:</p>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="sem_02" value="sem_02"><time>10:00</time> Aprende a Programar en una mañana</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="sem_03" value="sem_03"><time>17:00</time> Diseño UI y UX para móviles</label>
                          </div>
                      </div> <!--#sabado-->
                      <div id="domingo" class="contenido-dia clearfix">
                          <h4>Domingo</h4>
                          <div>
                                <p>Talleres:</p>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_12" value="taller_12"><time>10:00</time> Laravel</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_13" value="taller_13"><time>12:00</time> Crea tu propia API</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_14" value="taller_14"><time>14:00</time> JavaScript y jQuery</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_15" value="taller_15"><time>17:00</time> Creando Plantillas para WordPress</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="taller_16" value="taller_16"><time>19:00</time> Tiendas Virtuales en Magento</label>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                                <p>Conferencias:</p>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_07" value="conf_07"><time>10:00</time> Como hacer Marketing en línea</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_08" value="conf_08"><time>17:00</time> ¿Con que lenguaje debo empezar?</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="conf_09" value="conf_09"><time>19:00</time> Frameworks y librerias Open Source</label>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                                <p>Seminarios:</p>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="sem_04" value="sem_04"><time>14:00</time> Creando una App en Android en una tarde</label>
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="registro[]" id="sem_05" value="sem_05"><time>17:00</time> Creando una App en iOS en una tarde</label>
                          </div>
                      </div> <!--#domingo-->
                  </div><!--.caja-->
            </div> <!--#eventos-->

            <div id="resumen" class="resumen clearfix">
                <h3>Pago y extras</h3>
                <div class="caja clearfix">
                    <div class="extras">
                        <div class="orden">
                            <label for="camisa_evento">Camisa del evento 10€<small>(promocion 7% dto.)</small></label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="camisa_evento" name="pedido_camisas" size="3" placeholder="0">
                        </div><!--.orden-->
                        <div class="orden">
                            <label for="etiquetas">Paquete de 10 etiquetas 2€<small>(HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, Chrome)</small></label>
                            <input type="number" min="0" id="etiquetas" name="pedido_etiquetas" size="3" placeholder="0">
                        </div><!--.orden-->
                        <div class="orden">
                            <label for="regalo">Seleccione un regalo</label><br>
                            <select id="regalo" name="regalo" required>
                                <option value="">-Seleccione un regalo--</option><!--.Esto sera despues modificado con JavaScript para que seleccione y elija un regalo-->
                                <option value="2">Etiquetas</option>
                                <option value="1">Pulseras</option>
                                <option value="3">Plumas</option>
                            </select>
                        </div><!--.orden-->
                        <input type="button" id="calcular" class="button" value="Calcular">
                    </div><!--.extras-->

                    <div class="total">
                        <p>Resumen:</p>
                        <div id="lista_productos">

                        </div>
                        <p>Total:</p>
                        <div id="suma-total">

                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="total_pedido" id="total_pedido">
                        <input id="btnRegistro" type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Pagar">
                    </div><!--.caja-->
                </div><!--#resumen-->
            </div>

        </form>

    </section>

   <?php include_once 'includes/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

Creo que de aquí es donde tiene que estar el fallo por que si no me equivoco no coge la información de otro lado.

He introducido el `<?php print_r($_POST); die ?>` de esta forma en el codigo:

```
<?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>
 <?php print_r($_POST); die ?>

    <section class="seccion contenedor">
        <h2>Registro de Usuarios</h2>
```

Debajo de ese h2 viene el resto del código que te puse antes pero para no marear tanto lo he omitido en este comentario. Bien al poner el `<?php print_r($_POST); die ?>` , que no se si estará bien echo por que es la primera vez que lo utilizo (sorry), me ha devuelto una array vacía y la pagina no me sale nada solamente el `<?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>` con su respectiva características que le di con css. Posdata perdona por la tardanza en responder, pero están haciendo obras en mi casa y me va el Internet fatal.

He echo tal cual me has dicho en el ultimo comentario y al rellenar el formulario me ha dado esto en la siguiente pagina:

> Notice: Undefined index: registro in 
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\validar_registro.php on line 23
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in >D:\xampp\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\includes\funciones\funciones.php on line 29
>   string(39) "{"un_dia":2,"camisas":5,"etiquetas":10}"
>   string(2) "[]"

Me da exactamente igual que en el curso excepto con el error que me sale que en el curso no sale nada de eso.

Comment: Vale, perdona, culpa mia, quita el "die;". Creía que la parte en la que capturabas el $_POST y el html estaban en archivos distintos. Una vez quites el die te pintara un array vacio pero te saldrá la pagina web. Rellena el formulario y dale a enviar, cuando se recargue la pagina debe aparecerte un array con todo lo que lleva la variable $_POST; Cuando aparezca postea el resultado para que pueda verlo

Comment: No he echo nada en absoluto pero he recargado la pagina y he vuelto a rellenar el formulario y el error ha desaparecido. Le he quitado el print_r($_POST) para ver si era eso lo que me lo había solucionado pero no sigue sin aparecerme el error. No entiendo nada, porque solo he echo lo que tu me dijiste. Ha influido en algo ese print_r($_POST) ??. Voy a continuar con el curso y te comunico algo si me vuelvo a salir.  Muchas gracias por todo y perdona las molestias. Posdata sabes como ha podido desaparecer el error?? Solo he echo lo que te me has dicho nada mas.

Comment: Vi que tu input registro son checkbox, si al momento de enviar el formulario no has dado click en ninguno, no se enviarán por la petición `$_POST`

Comment: Por eso era que marcaba el error?? Por no haberle dado antes a ninguno??

Comment: @Manuel así es, debes validar que no esté vacío `$_POST['registro']`

Comment: @KacosPro tiene razón, perdona por no darme cuenta antes pero creía que lo tenías en archivos distintos al haberlo puesto en partes distintas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

No tienes ningun error de sintaxis.

> Notice: Undefined index: registro in D:\xampp\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\validar_registro.php on line 25

Te esta diciendo que no existe valor en la variable $_POST en el índice 'registro'. A raiz de ahí el segundo fallo:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\includes\funciones\funciones.php on line 29

Es porque **$eventos** esta vacío debido al primer fallo.

Revisa bien tu formulario y mira que el nombre 'registro' este registrado en el input del que deseas coger la información.
Un saludo.

Comment: Vale reviso y te comento, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola buenas @montes18295 he recibido el código desde donde se coge la información de registro pero es muy largo y no me deja ponerlo en comentario, perdona mi torpeza pero soy nuevo en la materia

Comment: No apareció nada, edita la pregunta y pones ahí el registro, así se verá más claro. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya esta editada la pregunta perdona las molestias

Comment: Perdona, Puedes hacer un print_r($_POST);die; al principio de registro.php para ver que lleva la peticion post?